# Project structure for golang, docker, gradle

Tags: docker, go, gradle

I am just starting with Go (golang) and want to get a new project folder structure set up for a project that will be built with Gradle and deployed to a Docker image.  I'm struggling to determine what this project structure might look like, primarily because of the GOPATH structure and the fact that the Go language tooling seems to be antithetical to using Gradle or to configuring a project that can be cloned (Git).

The project will eventually contain various server-side code written in Go, client side code written in HTML and JavaScript, so I need a project structure that works well for Gradle to build and package all of these kinds of pieces.

Does anyone have a good working structure and tooling recommendations for this?

Comment: Some good recent work here on GoGradle (https://github.com/gogradle/gogradle) and a blog post by Ben Muschko that I think may get you started: http://bmuschko.com/blog/golang-with-gradle/

Comment: I have been trying to use the gogradle plugin, and it claims to work outside of the $GOPATH, but apparently when you try to do this, it attempts to create some symbolic links, which fail to be created for me. What I am trying to do is set up a project structure that can be cloned from Git and run anywhere.  But I can't get this to work with gogradle because the .go files are not in a $GOPATH type of structure and the plugin can't create the symbolic links it wants to.

Answer (score 3):

When I started with Go, I fiddled with a rather wide variety of build tools, from [maven](http://maven.apache.org) to [gulp](https://gulpjs.com).

It turned out that at least for me, they were doing more harm than good, so I started to use Go's seemingly unimposing, but really well thought out features. One of them is[**`go generate`**](https://blog.golang.org/generate). Add simple shell scripts or occasionally Makefiles for automation.

## Sample project

I have put together a sample project to make this more clear

```
/Users/you/go/src/bitbucket.org/you/hello/
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── _templates
│   └── main.html
└── main.go
```

### main.go

This is a simple web server which serves "Hello, World!" using a template which is embedded into the binary using the excellent [go.rice](https://github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice) tool:

```
//go:generate rice embed-go

package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    rice "github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice"
)

func main() {

    templateBox, err := rice.FindBox("_templates")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // get file contents as string
    templateString, err := templateBox.String("main.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // parse and execute the template
    tmplMessage, err := template.New("message").Parse(templateString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if err := tmplMessage.Execute(w, map[string]string{"Greeting": "Hello, world!"}); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8080", nil))
}
```

Note the line

```
//go:generate rice embed-go
```

When you call `go generate` your source file will be scanned for such lines and the according commands will be executed. In this case, a file called rice-embed.go will be generated and your directory will look like this:

```
/Users/you/go/src/bitbucket.org/you/hello/
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── _templates
│   └── main.html
├── main.go
└── rice-box.go
```

You could call webpack in a `//go generate` for example, to get your stuff together and another generate to create a `rice-box.go` from the result. This way, all your stuff would be embedded in your binary and would become a breeze to deploy.

### Dockerfile

I have used a rather simple Dockerfile for this example:

```
FROM alpine:latest
MAINTAINER You <you@example.com>
COPY hello /usr/bin
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/usr/bin/hello"]
```

However this brings us to a problem: We can not use `go:generate` to produce the docker image, as of the time when we need to call `go:generate`, the new binary is not build yet. This would make us do ugly things like

```
go generate && go build && go generate
```

leading to the docker image build twice and whatnot. So, we need a different solution

### Solution A: A shell script

We could of course come up with something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Checks for existence omitted for brevity
GO=$(which go)
DOCKER=$(which docker)
$GO generate
$GO test
$GO build
$DOCKER -t you/hello .
```

However, this comes with a problem: you will always do the whole sequence using the shell script. Even when you just want to run the tests, you would end up building the docker image. Over time, this adds up. In such situations I tend to use

### Solution B: a Makefile

A Makefile is a configuration file for [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

```
    CC = $(shell which go 2>/dev/null)
    DOCKER = $(shell which docker 2>/dev/null)

    ifeq ($(CC),)
    $(error "go is not in your system PATH")
    else
    $(info "go found")
    endif

    ifeq ($(DOCKER),)
    $(error "docker not in your system path")
    else
    $(info "docker found")
    endif

    .PHONY: clean generate tests docker all

    all: clean generate tests hello docker

    clean:
        $(RM) hello rice-box.go cover.out
    generate:
        $(CC) generate
    tests: generate
        $(CC) test -coverprofile=cover.out
    hello: tests
        $(CC) build
    docker: hello
        $(DOCKER) build -t sosample/hello .
```

A full explanation is beyond the scope of this answer, but what you can basically do here is that you can call `make` and the `all` target will be built: files from the old build are removed (`clean`), a new `rice-box.go` is generated (`generate`) and so on. But in case you only want to run the tests for example, calling `make test` would only execute the targets `clean`, `generate` and `tests`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Although this doesn't include Gradle, I could look at what might be necessary to adapt your approach to my needs.

Comment: @MBru That was exactly my point - get rid of the dependency on the JVM and gradle in exchange for more ubiquitous tools.

Comment: But in the end, you are using 'make'.  And if you are going to use make, I'm not sure I see the advantage of also using go generate as those commands could be in the makefile just as easily.  Anyway, I appreciate your input here.  I may end up going in a similar direction.

Comment: @MBru Make is available out of the box on all but the most special Linux Distributions and UNIX derivates. The general idea here is the to use only tools from the Go ecosystem to provide everything needed to be able to get the program running. This way, somebody who only has Go installed can still use your program. The Makefile for additional stuff like packaging, containerization and alike - things you would only need under certain circumstances. And when it is there, *you* can use it for additional convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to my approach to structure your project https://github.com/alehano/gobootstrap
It's a web framework.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Not sure this addresses my question though.  I wasn't seeking a web application framework structure.  I'm really looking for a way I can build Go language code, deploy it in Docker, and test the code, all from a Gradle build environment.

Comment: Yeah, it's suitable for your needs. Instead of Docker integration. But it's not so hard.